# :hover and :focus inline style in React doesn't work

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to create a const object, which is supposed to be a button with React inline styling, but `:hover` and `:focus` doesn't work. How do I implement hover and focus in React?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

```
const Button= {
  background: '#AC003B',
  color: '#fff',
  borderColor: '#AC003B',
  &:hover, &:focus {
    background: '#707070',
    borderColor: '#707070'
  }       
}
```

Comment: Your snippet is not proper Javascript, is this object supposed to be the object you pass to style prop or what? You won't be able to set hover or focus styling in inline style, just like in regular HTML. Are you using some CSS in JS library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe what you want to do is:

```
const Button = {
  background: '#AC003B',
  color: '#fff',
  borderColor: '#AC003B',
  '&:hover, &:focus': {
    background: '#707070',
    borderColor: '#707070'
  }       
}
```