# React inline styles does not work with ":hover" state

Tags: reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd

I'm trying to add some styles to draggable item in react beautiful dnd.
However, styles for ":hover" state does not work.

Where could be an error in code:

```
           <div className="DraggableItem"
                ref={provided.innerRef}
                isDragging={snapshot.isDragging}
                {...provided.draggableProps}
                {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                style={snapshot.isDragging ? {
                    borderColor:"#14aaf5",
                    ...provided.draggableProps.style
                } : {
                    borderColor:"#fff",
                    ":hover": {
                        borderColor: "#cbd4db"
                    },
                    ...provided.draggableProps.style
                }}
            >
```

Comment: inline style doesn't support pseudo element. So, `:hover` doesn't work. You have to make it available in your internal styles.

Comment: However, in the past it was possible. Is it new rules in React?

Comment: No. It was never possible.

Comment: But i found on the StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61872517/hover-and-focus-inline-style-in-react-doesnt-work But it does not work in my code

Comment: That is not inline style. That is css in jss.